# Implementing AdMob Rewarded Video with LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am creating a game with LibGDX and wanted to put rewarded videos on it but I can't figure out how I do that.

I have already displayed an admob banner with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwAN4LMXo58

I have already seen this question but don't understand where to put this code:

```
public void showVideoAd(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (mAd.isLoaded()) {
                   mAd.show();
                } else {
                    loadRewardedVideoAd();
                }
            }
        });
}

public boolean hasVideoReward(){

    return isRewardLoaded; 
    //return mAd.isLoaded();    // -> must be called on the main UI thread.
}
```

(first of all there is no mAd declared in it): [rewarded video ad example in libGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397952/rewarded-video-ad-example-in-libgdx)

And using a few more sorces I've made a few experiments being the last one:

AdHandler.java:

```
public interface AdHandler {
    public void showVideo();
}
```

AndroidLauncher:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdHandler {
    RewardedVideoAd rewardedVideoAd;

    @Override
    public void showVideo() {
        if (rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            rewardedVideoAd.show();
        }
    }

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
            initialize(new Restart(this), config);

            rewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
            rewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

            }
        });

        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        rewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

Then I have this code on the android class:

```
AdHandler adHandler;

    public Restart(AdHandler handler) {
         this.adHandler = handler;
    }
```

And finnally I just call

```
    adHandler.showVideo();
```

on the render() what gives the error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: isLoaded must be called on the main
>   UI thread.

(that I really don't know what means)

If anyone could give me a full working project with LibGDX + AdMob Rewarded Videos would be awesome.

[EDIT]

So after a few tests I've been able to make it work, I only had to change

```
    @Override
    public void showVideo() {
        if (rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            rewardedVideoAd.show();
        }
    }
```

to

```
@Override
public void showVideo() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            if (rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                rewardedVideoAd.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and that solved the error I've said earlier.

So now the code is like this:

AdHandler.java: unchanged

Andoid Launcher:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdHandler {
    RewardedVideoAd rewardedVideoAd;

    @Override
    public void showVideo() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                if (rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    rewardedVideoAd.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new Restart(this), config);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        rewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        rewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        rewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
                rewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Andoid Class:

```
public class RewVideo extends ApplicationAdapter {
    AdHandler adHandler;
    public Restart(AdHandler handler) {
        this.adHandler = handler;
    }


    @Override
    public void create () {

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            adHandler.showVideo();
        }
    }
```

However, it fills my log with strange messages and exceptions:

> W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
>          java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement" on path:
>
> The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase.
>   Admob/Firbase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but
>   Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
>
> W/Ads: Server parameters: {...}
>
> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite not found.
>
> W/OkHttpClient: A connection to https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
>
> W/MessageQueue: Handler (android.os.Handler) {c84505c} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {c84505c} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>
> W/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Sent message(1) after release. Message ignored.
>
> E/ACodec: [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010

And while video is playing this message appears like once a second:

> W/zygote: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

And more than being tons of messages, I've also noticed that there are two messages for each of these: "Ad finished loading", "Ad opening" and "Ad closed"

Is this normal?