# How to implement RewardedVideo ad with libgdx on Android?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob-rewardedvideoad

I want to implemento a RewardedVideo ad in my game so the user can keep playing the game, but if the user does not want to see the ad then he has to start over.

The thing is... I tried some code I could find on google but it does not seem to work properly, it does not even ask the user if he wants to see it or not, it actually seems like a regular Interstitial ad.

I've basically tried what I found here [Implementing AdMob Rewarded Video with LibGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517317/implementing-admob-rewarded-video-with-libgdx) but I got the result I've mentioned above

Could anyone give me any tip, some tutorial, documentation or step by step that actually works? I've implemented BannerAd and Interstitial with no problem, I'm struggling with the RewardedVideo though.